# Simple objects with isomorphic projective covers

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, projective-module

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two simple objects of an abelian category. Assume that they have projective covers $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$.

**Question**: If $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ are isomorphic, is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are also isomorphic?

Comment: There must be something I'm missing: If by "$X,Y$ are simple" you mean "they have no nontrivial subobjects" aren't they already projective? The ker-object-coker exact sequence $0 \to K \to X \to PX \to 0$ splits. But then $PX=0$ or $X$.

Comment: @fosco The projective cover of $X$ maps onto $X$, $PX\to X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are nonisomorphic simple objects which both have $P$ as a projective cover. Let $K$ be the kernel of $P\to X$. Then $K$ is not in the kernel of $P\to Y$, so $K\to Y$ is epi, since $Y$ is simple. So the epimorphism $P\to Y$ is not essential.

Comment: By *essential* I guess you mean superfluous (or coessential), right?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes, those are terms that mean the same, but I’m used to, and prefer, the term “essential epimorphism”. (It seems to me that it’s the kernel that’s superfluous, not the epimorphism itself. And “coessential” just seems ugly to me. When you dualize a concept, you don’t dualize all of its attributes: if something is beautiful then its dual counterpart  is probably also beautiful, not cobeautiful.)